# Themosis Framework Collection Loop - WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I've been using Themosis for a while now and am new to the "Collection" metafield.

I have the following metadata retrieved from my Collection of [type => "image"]:

```
a:9:{i:0;s:4:"1892";i:1;s:4:"1891";i:2;s:4:"1890";i:3;s:4:"1888";i:4;s:4:"1887";i:5;s:4:"1886";i:6;s:4:"1885";i:7;s:4:"1884";i:8;s:4:"1883";}
```

Additionally, I know `i` = index and the quoted numbers are the image attachment IDs. What is the `a:9` and `s:4` in any case?

I can't seem to find any [Themosis documentation](https://framework.themosis.com/docs/1.3/field#collection-field) on how to loop through a collection with metadata as described above.

Comment: you need to serialize array before getting this

Comment: okay ```unserialize()``` worked perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was your serialized array you need to unrealized this array before getting this.

```
a:9:{i:0;s:4:"1892";i:1;s:4:"1891";i:2;s:4:"1890";i:3;s:4:"1888";i:4;s:4:"1887";i:5;s:4:"1886";i:6;s:4:"1885";i:7;s:4:"1884";i:8;s:4:"1883";}
```

You can use **`unserialize()`** function to full fill your achievement.

Answer (score 1):

I never really thought of serializing and un-serializing the data. Nonetheless, this is what worked for me:

```
<?php $images = isset($meta['gallery']) ? unserialize(reset($meta['gallery'])) : false; ?>

@if($images && !empty($images))
    @foreach($images as $key => $img)
        // Do the things here
    @endforeach
@endif
```